# Why ci" commands is not working for VI editor

Tags: vi

I was just reading one of the post here on SO regarding different tricks used in VI editor ,there i read one trick

```
    ci"    -> Cut everything inside "" string and start insert mode
```

but when i tried this is not working for me

```
 main()
{
int a[]="amit singh tomar";
}

:ci""
```

this is how am doing it.
But text written in "" is not getting deleted.Please let me know am i doing it wrong or what??

Answer (score 4):

You must not type `:ci""`. It works like this:

Make sure you are in normal mode (press ESC), and then type `ci"` - literally: first a `c`, then `i` and then `"`.

Comment: Thanks @nightcracker but i really don't know how to get into the normal mode?

Comment: Pressing escape will always get you into normal mode. Also, you must know that if you get better at vi(m) you will be in normal mode at all times, unless you are typing.

Comment: But as soon as I pressed c line pointed by cursor is got deleted even before I press i".

Comment: @Amit Singh Tomar: what kind of vi do you use, and on what platform?

Answer (score 1):

While your cursor is on the string, and you are in normal mode (i.e not in insertion mode, nor in command mode), just try typing `ci"`, without the starting `:`.

Answer (score 1):

It works in normal mode. Try without the colon at the beginning.